# Short alias for file in bash command

Tags: bash, unix

I want a short way to access files, which I usually use in bash.
For example, see logs. Now I use:

```
less /var/log/user/server.log
less /var/log/user/server2.log
```

I want shortcut, to do

```
less server.log
less server2.log
```

I try this variant in .bash_profile, but there is a mistake somewhere:

```
less() { if [[ $@ == "server.log" ]]; then command less /var/log/user/server.log; else command less "$@"; fi; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could *symlink* the files like so:

```
ln -s /var/log/user/server.log server.log
ln -s /var/log/user/server2.log server2.log
```

And then you can do whatever you want with these files as:

```
less server.log
tail -f server2.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I got bored so I wrote this bash shell function for you:

```
less()
{
    OIFS="$IFS"; IFS=:
    lesspath=('' $LESSPATH)
    IFS="$OIFS"
    for arg ; do
            for path in "${lesspath[@]}" ; do
                    file="${path:+$path/}${arg}"
                    if [[ -e "${file}" ]] ; then
                            command less "${file}"
                            continue 2
                    fi
            done
            command less "${arg}"
    done
}
```

Put this shell function into your `.bashrc`, set `LESSPATH=/var/log/user` and now you can run less as you want to.

You can add other paths to `LESSPATH` by separating them with colons, just like the other PATH environment variables. So, if you set `LESSPATH=/var/log:/var/log/user`, you could also easily run `less syslog` from anywhere to easily see `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 0):

```
serverlog=/var/log/user/server.log
serverlog2=/var/log/user/server2.log

less $serverlog
```

Answer (score 0):

To use aliases you could do something like this too..

add this to .bashrc

```
function lss { less "$1"; }
export lss
alias lf='echo /var/log/syslog'
```

run

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Now you can do :

```
less $(lf)
```

or

```
lss $(lf)
```